# Get the value inside element give me double \n in empty case

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 5 and html table to render a view. In one of the table cell, I want to check if the value inside the td tag is null or not and show or hide an item using JQuery.
I am using the code below but for some reasons the value inside the tag is showing "\n \n"
and therefore always not null. I have included a screen and my code. Any help to remove "\n \n" so I can check if the value is null or not will be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function()
{
var v = $("#hideheader").html(); ----> This value here is showing "\n \n"
if(v=='') --- This is always not empty
{
alert('empty');
$("#hide").hide();
}
else
{
alert('non-empty value');
}
});
});
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr> <th id="hide">ID</th></tr> </thead>
<tbody><tr><td id="hideheader">@item.adminstring</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.is(':empty')` instead of `.html()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
         var isEmpty = $("#hideheader").is(':empty');
         if(isEmpty) 
         {
              alert('empty');
              $("#hide").hide();
          }
          else
          {
             alert('non-empty value');
           }
     });
 });
```

**Update :** 
you can get the text and for your case replace unwanted characters with an empty string :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
     var hideHeaderText = $("#hideheader").text();
     if(hideHeaderText.replace(/\r|\n/g, "") == "") 
     {
          alert('empty');
          $("#hide").hide();
      }
      else
      {
         alert('non-empty value');
       }
 });
```

});

Comment: Hi Thanks. I just tried your code above. Like I said there a value '\n' and there isEmpty is false instead of true

Comment: I've updated my answer with your demand. please check as the answer if your problem has solved. @user2061998

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got it working

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
         var v = $('#hideheader').html();
    var name = $.trim(v);
          if (name === '') {
                $("#hide").hide();

            } else {
                $("#hide").show();
            }
     });
 });
```